# How to get a particular value from a xml tag

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have to parse a XML file and create a drop-down list in my web application.
Right now, after parsing the XML the output looks something like -

scripts/testSuite/networkSecurity/802dot1x/802dot1xBasicFunctionality/802dot1xRadAccAVPClntStatIp.tcl
scripts/testSuite/networkSecurity/802dot1x/802dot1xConfiguration/802dot1xBasicUserMode.tcl

script is one of the tag of my XML file.

Now from this tag I just want the 2nd position (networkSecurity) nad last and print them.
How Can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `simplexml_load_file` — Interprets an XML file into an object

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");

echo $xml->data;
```

*UPDATE

to get a specific value by slash delimiter:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");

foreach($xml->testcase as $var){
    $var=explode('/',$var->script);
    echo $var[2] ."\n". end($var);
}
```

Comment: Orlo : I am already using it, and after parsing my big XML file i got this output .. this output is the content of one the tag of xml which looks like 
`<script>scripts/testSuite/networkSecurity/802dot1x/802dot1xBasicFunctionality/802dot1xSuppFailSuppAuthentication.tcl</script>`

what i want now is to get the 2nd position of this script tag and the last.

Comment: your idea works perfectly fine but there is one thing that is bugging me.
I am using the logic- 

`foreach ($testcase->script as $var)
{
$var=preg_replace('/<(.*?)>/','',$var);
$var=explode('/',$var);
echo $var[2] ."\n". end($var);
}`

as I have many script tags, but even after using foreach in the output I get value of last script tag only :(

Comment: try running print_r($var), see what each array looks like in foreach loop.

Comment: oohh i got the problem but don't know how to resolve it. Currently my php script looks like

Comment: `<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file('info.xml');

foreach ($xml->testcase as $testcase)
{
    echo $testcase->script . "<br>";
}

foreach ($testcase->script as $var)
{
$var=preg_replace('/<(.*?)>/','',$var); // remove html tag
$var=explode('/',$var);
echo $var[2] ."\n". end($var);
print_r($var);
}
?>`

Comment: Now the first foreach loop is storing the last value as it is not an array. What I need to do is safe the value of $testcase->script in an array

Comment: can you upload the `info.xml` so I can test?

Comment: I have a doubt .. Why it is printing networkSecurity  only once ?
And is there a way to store the vale of $var[2] and end($var) in an array so that I can use them for getting my drop down list in the UI ?
My answer looks like [output](http://pastebin.com/MFYDyy15)

Comment: why once? if you still can't see it add another \n at the beginning -- `echo "\n" . $var[2] ."\n". end($var);`. to store it in another array do: $arrayB[].=$var[2] . "," . end($var);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $xml, $values, $indexes);
xml_parser_free($parser);
```

where $xml is your xml, $values and $indexes will be the returned arrays containing the xml tags found and their position.